# Windows service fails to start up after certain number of instances

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service

I develop a .Net WCF web service hosted as a windows service on Windows XP for development and Windows Server 2003 SP2 for deployment. We install several instances of the service (one for each logical environment) in one machine. After a certain number of instances the windows service fails to startup. The number of services that can be simultaneously running varies. The services run with a specific service account that has local admin rights. I have even created a simple windows service in .Net that does no WCF but just logs a timestamp to a log file and the behaviour is still the same. After certain number of services have been started the next one doesn't start. If I stop one of the running service and then try to start the service that failed it starts up. I am 100% sure it is nothing to do with application code. The number of instances that can be started increases after I reboot the machine but eventually it will hit a limit.

The error message when trying to start up from service control panel is

```
---------------------------  
TestService18.exe - Application Error
---------------------------
The exception unknown software exception (0xc06d007e) occurred in the application at location 0x7c812afb.


---------------------------
OK   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on what can be causing this error.

Comment: How many instances of the service are we talking about before the failure condition? 10, 50, 100,1000?

Comment: About 20 on Server 2003. But can vary from 15-25. On XP can vary from 5 - 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is experienced by [others as well](http://www.itnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.windows.server.general/topic29673.aspx)
It is probably due to [desktop heap exhaustion](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx).
We tried the registry changes suggested but didn't work.
Finally our systems guy investigated that the windows 2003 servers has [/3GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791558.aspx) and [/userva](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810371) boot parameters enabled. Removing these boot parameters and restarting the machines did the trick and all services would startup simultaneously now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... that's an odd one. [You're not the only one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/clr/thread/9f00bdf0-3ea7-4a1f-b5a7-9b5bbc009888) who has [seen this](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic28620.aspx). I suspect you're hitting a child process limit of some kind, but I'm not sure what would be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not a programmer, but I came across this. Hope it helps.

http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/03/23/wcf-configuration-default-limits-concurrency-and-scalability.aspx

Comment: This is nothing to with my issue. Even withiot WCF I have trouble starting plaim simple windows services.